# How do request to external resource in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need get data from external service. It has API. This is example:
http://portal.example.com/portal.api?l=username&p=keyphrase&act=brand_by_nr&nr=kl2&alt

Parameters are:
"l" - login, "p" - password, "act" - function to execute, "nr" - part number

I try connect by Meteor http.This is my server code:

```js
var sources = {
    mskv: {
        url: "http://portal.example.com/portal.api",
        auth: { l: "mylogin", p: "cBKoTyalCgbOQb37NG6sbb0qv2I0Q4PmWRJIJMWpOhCPFombqeDv7fBhdkjsdhkjah" },
        params: { act: "brand_by_nr", nr: null }
    }
};


Meteor.methods({
    doRequest: function(partNumber) {
        for (var key in sources) {
            var url = sources[key].url;
            var authData = sources[key].auth;
            var paramsData = sources[key].params;

            paramsData.nr = partNumber;

            HTTP.call("POST", url, { auth: authData, params: paramsData }, function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    throw new Meteor.Error("not-response", "Remote server not responding");
                }
               
                return res;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is my client code:

```js
Template.search.events({
    "click .search": function(event) {
        var partNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("input")[0].value;

        Meteor.call("doRequest", partNumber, function(err, res) {
            if(err === "not-response") return;

            console.log(res);
        });
    }
});
```

I have error:

```
> Exception while invoking method 'doRequest' TypeError: Object
> #<Object> has no method 'indexOf' I20150227-00:01:35.455(3)?     at Object._call (packages/http/httpcall_server.js:42:1)
> I20150227-00:01:35.455(3)?     at Object._.extend.wrapAsync [as call]
> (packages/meteor/helpers.js:118:1) I20150227-00:01:35.455(3)?     at
> [object Object].Meteor.methods.doRequest (app/server/server.js:19:18)
```

Can you help me, where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case auth field is not correct. The true way is auth:"login: password", look as simply string. Second error - auth field is not need. For this service login and password send as parameters { params: {l:"login", p: "password", act: "brand_by_nr" ....} }

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var paramsData = [sources[key].params];
```

I suspect it's looking for an array there.